# How to do type ahead search in SQL server database

Tags: sql-server, django, indexing, linked-server, type-ahead

I am writing back-end API in Django for an Angular front-end application. I am using an SQL-server database and a linked server. In the front-end I want to use type-ahead search for employees. For ex. In front-end if I want to search for employees having names 'Lisha' then while typing the name itself data is fetched from database (linked server).

Currently I am using a query like:

```
select * from openquery([LinkedServer], 'select employeeName from "DB"."View" where "employeeName" LIKE "%Lisha%"')
```

The query will search for all the name like 'Lisha' and then return the result set which I am sending to the front-end. But what I want is as soon as user type 'L' the result should start coming and I can send the result to frontend without waiting for the all the name having 'L' query getting completed.

The query I am using is very slow as it waits for all the names having 'Lisha' to get finished and then the result set I can send to the front-end.

How can I make it faster and how can I use type ahead search?

Comment: The query you have will search for any names that have "Lisha" in it. Is that what you want? Or do you want to find the names that START with "Lisha"?  Hopefully you have an index on employeeName, but given the use of the % at the start and end of your search term you are going to do an index scan every time you submit that query..

Comment: "Lisha" it can be present anywhere, as it could be first name, last name or middle name or it can be anywhere if user searching with email id or username

Answer (score 1):

From what you want to achieve, I can suggest sending a request to the backend from angular application as the user starts typing and returning a limited(say 20) set of results to the user for the search term in the request. If the user already typed the next character(s) and the  the current request has not yet completed, then cancel the current request and switch to the new request. You can also add a 'debounce time' to wait for a certain time after the user has paused typing before sending the request. Example below :

```
  public search(searchTerm: Observable<string>): any {
    return searchTerm.pipe(
     //wait for 500 milliseconds before sending the request
      debounceTime(500),
     //Send the request only if the current search term is different ftom previous search 
      //term
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    //Cancel the request if not completed, and make a new request
      switchMap(term =>
        term.trim().length > 2 ? this.getSearchTerm(term) : of([])
      ),
      map(response => {

        const name= this.filterName(response);
        console.log(address);
        return address;
      })
    );
  }

private getSearchTerm(term) {
    const apiURL = `${your-base-url}type-ahead-search?searchString=${term}`;
    return this.http.get(apiURL);
  }
```

Your search results depends on your backend implementation. I would suggest, instead of using 'like' in queries for automcomplete use [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/search-text-with-regular-expressions?view=sql-server-ver15) for searching text. Regular expressions are a concise and flexible notation for finding patterns of text.

I used elasticsearch for the backend implementation. If interested you might like reading [Prefix Queries](https://blog.mimacom.com/autocomplete-elasticsearch-part1/) and [Edge NGram Tokenizer](https://blog.mimacom.com/autocomplete-elasticsearch-part2/) on how to do it.